# Node process.env setup not working on npm config library

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, production-environment, production

I am using 'config' library from npm.

I have folder like this

1.config/development.json (my development config)

2.config/production.json (my production config)

I am using nodemon and my package.json looks like below:

```
{
  "name": "superapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A SuperAppSoftware",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",

    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server-dev\" \"npm run client-dev\"",
    "client-dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "server-dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&& nodemon server/server.js",

    "prod": "concurrently \"npm run server-prod\" \"npm run client-prod\"",
    "client-prod": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline  --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000",
    "server-prod": "set NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon server/server.js",

    "build": "webpack"
  },
}
```

In this package.json i am setting set NODE_ENV but the if i start **npm run prod** still the development.json inside config file working, but not production.json working.

Comment: Try with `"server-prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server/server.js"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your package.json use:

```
"server-dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/server.js"
```

and

```
"server-prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server/server.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

To add some informations :

For project where people work on windows and some people on linux, you can use the package cross-env : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

```
"server-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon server/server.js"
```